# Mosfet layout, Arduino and RPI

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get an arduino to switch on something on the Raspberry Pi with a Mosfet.

Would this layout work?

[image]

Comment: What is the MOSFET for?  Why not just connect the PI and Arduino grounds and connect an Arduino gpio set as an output to a Pi gpio set as an input (with a resistor divider if it's a 5V Arduino)?

Answer (score 2):

Joan is right. If you are trying to have an output on the Arduino trigger an input on the pi, then you merely need to use 2 resistors and create a voltage divider to change the 5V out of the arduino to 3V. The mosfet is unnecessary.

(Alternatively, if you've got more than one pin to connect you could use a buffer IC like the 74HC4050.)